# Cross Site AJAX Request

Tags: jquery, ajax

What I am exactly trying to build is, an INTERFACE through which a user can send post request to my site and display the response on his browser.

For example

```
$.post(
     'http://www.mysite.com/thirdpartyrequest.php',
     { param1: value1, param2: value2 },
     function(data) {
         $("#universalid").html(data);//Update with the response
     }
);
//however it is not allowed.
```

Any Idea how to do such Cross Site Ajax Request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to use JSONP. Check out:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

If you have a server providing data such as:

```
http://my.server.com/somedata.json

{
   'some': ['fancy', 'json' ],
   'structure: 'here'
}
```

You turn this into jsonp by providing a callback parameter in the request url - the de facto standard name for it is `callback`. Then on the server, you need to check this parameter and wrap your result in that callback (effectively turning it into javascript instead of json).

```
http://my.server.com/somedata.json?callback=receive_this

receive_this({
   'some': ['fancy', 'json' ],
   'structure: 'here'
});
```

(For the niggly, the response mime type for json should be `application/json` whilst for jsonp it should be `application/javascript`)

The client will now (conceptually) load the json like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var receive_this = function(json) {

     // do some stuff with data here.

   };

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://my.server.com/somedata.json?callback=receive_this"></script>
```

In practice you use something like jQuery to dynamically insert the jsonp request script tag into the DOM. jQuery defaults to calling the callback request parameter `callback`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://my.server.com/somedata.json',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: receive_this
});
```

Comment: It says something about JSONP API, what is that. How to create that

Comment: Can i use php to create .JSON files? But how to output  `
receive_this({ 'some': ['fancy', 'json' ], 'structure: 'here' });` can `json_encode` output the array in that format.

Comment: I'm useless with php, but it seems pretty straightforward according to this: http://1080d.com/lang/en-us/2009/10/converting-php-to-jsonp-with-json_encode/